Pink haired woman dressed as an alien teaches you about outer space
I am trying to remember the name of a old VHS I had from late 80s early 90s. It was a educational show that had this women dressed as a alien with crazy red/pink hair and goggles for eyes. She would teach you about outer-space. I've tried to Google it but nothing comes up. I think her name was Bippy.
Which show was this?

Movie or TV show? English? Where did you see this?

 
The Vitsie Video Sitter series
This was a set of children's educational home videos, covering topics such as dinosaurs, oceans and space. Here's the dinosaur-themed video, you can watch the rest of that series here. Here's the blurb for the Vitsie Visits Space / Vitsie Space VHS:

Introduces children to various planets, asteroids and other celestial points of
  interests while rocketting with Vitsie on a cosmic adventure through
  the solar system. ~ From WorldCat

If you're interested, there are Ebay listings for the interactive CDs as well.

Could this be referring to "(Quantum Leap: )The Adventures of Pug and Zero"
This has two puppets as aliens; One has goggles. With a human girl who wears pink.
See this link for more information.
This is just a SWAG
